# Extension of the Jacobi triple product identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, theta-functions

[The Jacobi triple product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) identity is:
$$\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})(1+zq^{2n-1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2}  $$

I would like to extend the idea for $\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3} $

My idea is below for extension:

Let's assume we define $G(z,q,h)$ as

$$G(z,q,h)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3} $$

$$G(z,q,h)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3} $$

$z=ZQ^{2}h^{3}$

$q=Qh^{3}$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+ZQ^{2}h^{3}(Qh^{3})^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+(ZQ^2h^3)^{-1}(Qh^3)^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{2n}h^{3n} Q^{n^2} h^{3n^2} h^{n^3} $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+ZQ^{2n+1}h^{3n^2+3n+1})(1+Z^{-1}Q^{2n-3}h^{-3n^2+9n-7})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{2n+n^2}h^{3n+3n^2+n^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\frac{(1+Z^{-1}Q^{-1}h^{-1})}{(1+ZQh)}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+ZQ^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+Z^{-1}Q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{2n+n^2}h^{3n+3n^2+n^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\frac{(1+Z^{-1}Q^{-1}h^{-1})}{(1+ZQh)} \frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{n^2} h^{n^3}}{G(Z,Q,h)}=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{2n+n^2}h^{3n+3n^2+n^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{n^2} h^{n^3}=G(Z,Q,h)ZQh\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{2n+n^2}h^{3n+3n^2+n^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{n^2} h^{n^3}=G(Z,Q,h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^{n+1} Q^{1+2n+n^2}h^{1+3n+3n^2+n^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{n^2} h^{n^3}=G(Z,Q,h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^{n+1} Q^{(n+1)^2}h^{(n+1)^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{n^2} h^{n^3}=G(Z,Q,h)\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty Z^n Q^{n^2} h^{n^3}  $$

$$G(ZQ^{2}h^{3},Qh^{3},h)=G(Z,Q,h) \tag 1$$

If $h=1$ then
$G(z,q,1)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})$ can be gotten from Jacobi_triple_product.

I really wonder how I can find the function $G(z,q,h)$. Please help me which Technics can be applied to find it. Also If you know there is other works about this subject, please share links and references.

Thanks a lot for responses.

Note:
If $z=x^3$,$q=x^3$,$h=x$

$$G(x^3,x^3,x)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+x^3x^{6n-3}x^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+x^{-3}x^{6n-3}x^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty x^{3n} x^{3n^2} x^{n^3} $$

$$xG(x^3,x^3,x)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+x^{3n^2+3n+1})(1+x^{-3n^2+9n-7})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty x^{1+3n+3n^2+n^3}  $$

$$xG(x^3,x^3,x)\frac{1}{(1+x)}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+x)(1+x^{3n^2+3n+1})(1+x^{-1})(1+x^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty x^{(n+1)^3}  $$

$$xG(x^3,x^3,x)\frac{(1+x^{-1})}{(1+x)}\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+x^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+x^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty x^{n^3}  $$

$$G(x^3,x^3,x)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+x^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+x^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty x^{n^3}  $$

The relation is below for $G()$ from Equation 1 If $z=x^3$,$q=x^3$,$h=x$

$$G(x^{12},x^6,x)=G(x^3,x^3,x) \tag 2$$

$$G(x^{12},x^6,x)=G(x^3,x^3,x)=G(1,1,x) \tag 3$$

EDIT: I thought If I can find a few term of $G(z,q,h)$ by hand and maybe seen what the pattern of $G(z,q,h)$. I really wonder if we can find $G(z,q,h)$ in product terms as Jacobi did in his product formula.

$$G(z,q,h)\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3} $$

$$G(z,q,h)(1+zqh)(1+z^{-1}q^{1}h^{-1})(1+zq^3h^7)(1+z^{-1}q^{3}h^{-7})....=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}  $$

$$G(z,q,h)(1+q^2+q(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}))(1+q^6+q^3(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7}))...=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}$$

$$G(z,q,h)(1+q^2+q^6+q^8+q(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^7(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^3(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^5(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^4(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7}))...=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3} $$

$$G(z,q,h)( 1+q^2+q^6+q^8+q(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^7(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^3(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^5(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^4(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+q^4(h^{6}+h^{-6}))...=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3} $$

$$G(z,q,h)( 1+q^2+q^6+q^8+q(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^7(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^3(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^5(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^4(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+q^4(h^{6}+h^{-6}))...= 1+q (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^4 (z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+.... $$

EDIT: (Updated on 15th April)

We can see first 3 term of $G(z,q,h)$ easily.To find 4th term:
$$G(z,q,h)=1-q^2+q^3\left( (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}) - (zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7}) \right) +a_4 q^4 +....  $$

$$G(z,q,h)(1+q^2+q^6+q^8+q(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^7(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^3(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^5(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^4(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+q^4(h^{6}+h^{-6}))...= 1+q (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^4 (z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+.... $$

$$(1-q^2+q^3\left( (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}) - (zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7}) \right) +a_4 q^4 +.... ) (1+q^2+q^6+q^8+q(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^7(zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^3(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^5(zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7})+q^4(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+q^4(h^{6}+h^{-6}))...= 1+q (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1})+q^4 (z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})+.... $$

$a_4=-1+(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})-(z^2h^2+z^{-2}h^{-2})$

Thus first 4 terms of $G(z,q,h)$ is:

$$G(z,q,h)=1-q^2+q^3\left( (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}) - (zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7}) \right) + q^4 \left(-1+(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})-(z^2h^2+z^{-2}h^{-2})  \right) +....  $$

If we order it little bit more .

$$G(z,q,h)=1-q^2-q^4 +q^3\left( zh(1-h^6) + z^{-1}h^{-1}(1-h^{-6}) \right) + q^4 \left(z^2h^2(h^6-1)+z^{-2}h^{-2}(h^{-6}-1)  \right) +....  $$

I will update If I find more terms of $G(z,q,h)$

EDIT: (Updated on 17th April)

I have found 5th term .
$a_5= (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}) - (z h^{19}+z^{-1}h^{-19}) +(z^3 h^3+z^{-3}h^{-3}) - (z^3 h^9+z^{-3}h^{-9})$

$$G(z,q,h)=1-q^2+q^3\left( (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}) - (zh^7+z^{-1}h^{-7}) \right) + q^4 \left(-1+(z^2h^8+z^{-2}h^{-8})-(z^2h^2+z^{-2}h^{-2})  \right) + q^5\left( (zh+z^{-1}h^{-1}) - (z h^{19}+z^{-1}h^{-19}) +(z^3 h^3+z^{-3}h^{-3}) - (z^3 h^9+z^{-3}h^{-9}) \right)+ ....  $$

---

$$G(z,q,h)=1-q^2-q^4 +q^3\left( zh(1-h^6) + z^{-1}h^{-1}(1-h^{-6}) \right) + q^4 \left(z^2h^2(h^6-1)+z^{-2}h^{-2}(h^{-6}-1)  \right) + q^5 \left( zh(1-h^{18}) + z^{-1}h^{-1}(1-h^{-18})+z^3h^3(1-h^6)+z^{-3}h^{-3}(1-h^{-6})  \right)+....  $$

I have not seen a general pattern of the terms yet but I believe there is very beautiful pattern in it. If you help me to find more terms , I will be very appreciated. Maybe the pattern of terms of $G(z,q,h)$ can be seen more .Thanks.

EDIT: 27/01/2020

$$G(z,q,h)=\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}= C(q,h)+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{A_n(q,h)}{(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})}+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{B_n(q,h)}{(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}$$

If we apply $z-->z^{-1}$  and $h-->h^{-1}$

$$B_n(q,h)=A_n(q,h^{-1})$$
$$C(q,h)=C(q,h^{-1})$$

$$G(z,q,h)=\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}= C(q,h)+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{A_n(q,h)}{(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})}+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{A_n(q,h^{-1})}{(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}$$

If we apply

$z=ZQ^{2}h^{3}$

$q=Qh^{3}$

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}= C(qh^3,h)+\sum\limits_{n = 2 }^ \infty \frac{A_{n-1}(qh^3,h)}{(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})}+\frac{A_1(qh^3,h^{-1})}{(1+z^{-1}q^{-1}h^{-1})}+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{A_{n+1}(qh^3,h^{-1})}{(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}$$

$$A_{n+1}(q,h)=A_{n}(qh^3,h)$$  for $n>0$
$$C(q,h)=C(qh^3,h)-\frac{A_1(q,h)}{(1+zqh)}+\frac{A_1(qh^3,h^{-1})}{(1+z^{-1}q^{-1}h^{-1})}$$

$$C(q,h)=C(qh^3,h)-\frac{A_1(q,h)}{(1+zqh)}+\frac{A_1(qh^3,h^{-1})zqh}{(1+zqh)}$$
$$A_1(q,h)=C(qh^3,h)-C(q,h)$$
$$A_n(q,h)=C(qh^{3n},h)-C(qh^{3(n-1)},h)$$

$$G(z,q,h)=\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}= C(q,h)+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{C(qh^{3n},h)-C(qh^{3(n-1)},h)}{(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})}+\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ \infty \frac{C(qh^{-3n},h)-C(qh^{-3(n-1)},h)}{(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})}$$

$z=-q^{-1} h^{-1}$
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty (-1)^n q^{n^2-n} h^{n^3-n}}{\prod\limits_{n=2}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n-2}h^{3n^2-3n})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n}h^{-3n^2+3n})}= C(qh^{3},h)-C(q,h)$$

$q=qh^{-3/2}$

$$C(qh^{3/2},h)-C(qh^{-3/2},h)=\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty (-1)^n q^{n^2-n} h^{-3/2(n^2-n)} h^{n^3-n}}{\prod\limits_{n=2}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n-2}h^{-3(n-1)}h^{3n^2-3n})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n}h^{-3n^2})}$$

$$C(qh^{3/2},h)-C(qh^{-3/2},h)=\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty (-1)^n q^{n^2-n} h^{-3/2(n^2-n)} h^{n^3-n}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n}h^{3n^2})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n}h^{-3n^2})}$$

$$C(qh^{3/2},h)-C(qh^{-3/2},h)=\frac{\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty (-1)^{n+1} q^{n(n+1)} h^{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}}}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n}h^{3n^2})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n}h^{-3n^2})}$$

$q-->q^{1/2}$,
$h-->h^{1/3}$

$$[C(\sqrt{q/h},\sqrt[3] {h})-C(\sqrt{qh},\sqrt[3] {h})]\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n}h^{n^2})\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{n}h^{-n^2})=\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty (-1)^{n} q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} h^{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}$$

$$C(q,1)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }(1-q^{2n})$$

I do not know how to find $C(q,h)$ but few terms of it :
$$C(q,h)=C(q,h^{-1})=1-q^2-q^4+....$$

Maybe someone can help me to find more terms and its closed form.

Thanks a lot for helps

EDIT: 30/01/2020

I have new idea about zeros of $\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}$

The direction of this question will not give zeros for$\sum\limits_{n = - \infty }^ \infty z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}$ as @mr_e_man showed in his answer. Thus I will go in different way in another question.

I focused on zeros in a new question.
My new question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3528092/extention-of-jacobi-triple-for-sum-limits-n-infty-infty-zn-qn2):

Comment: This a very interesting result, it's hard to check but I will see when I have some time

Comment: Where did those products come from, with $h^{n^3-(n-1)^3}$? What if $G$ cancels those and replaces them with different products?

Comment: Notice that this only converges when $|h|=1$ and $|q|<1$. Including another factor $r^{n^4}$ with $|r|<1$ would make it converge for any $h\neq0$, but would obviously complicate everything. Yet the quartic form can be reparametrized, analogously to Ramanujan's theta function, as $$z^nq^{n^2}h^{n^3}r^{n^4}=a^{(n-3)(n-2)(n-1)n/4!}b^{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)/4!}c^{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)/4!}d^{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/4!}$$ which has the advantage that all exponents are non-negative. The sum converges at least when $|abcd|<1$. Another possible parametrization uses the exponents $n(n\pm1)/2,\;\big(n(n\pm1)/2\big)^2$.

Comment: And I think we should choose a parametrization (whether quartic or cubic) that simplifies nicely when $n$ is replaced with $n+1$.

Comment: On second thought, it looks like we can't avoid negative exponents; they appear with $n\mapsto n+1$, for example $a^{n(n-1)/2}b^{n(n+1)/2}\mapsto b(b^{-1})^{n(n-1)/2}(ab^2)^{n(n+1)/2}$. As for "simplifying nicely", I had in mind specifically $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a^nb^{\binom n2}c^{\binom n3}d^{\binom n4}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a^{n+1}b^{\binom{n+1}2}c^{\binom{n+1}3}d^{\binom{n+1}4}$$ $$=a\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(ab)^n(bc)^{\binom n2}(cd)^{\binom n3}d^{\binom n4}$$ because the binomial coefficients satisfy $\binom{n+1}k=\binom nk+\binom n{k-1}$.

Comment: Here's a promising special case: If we have a root of unity $h^6=1$, then $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}z^nq^{n^2}h^{n^3}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(zh)^nq^{n^2}$$ $$=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n})(1+zhq^{2n-1})(1+z^{-1}h^{-1}q^{2n-1})$$ $$=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n})(1+zq^{2n-1}h^{3n^2-3n+1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1}h^{-3n^2+3n-1})$$ since $n^3\equiv n\bmod6$ and $3n^2-3n=6\binom n2\equiv0\bmod6$.

Comment: Actually, reparametrizing $$z^nq^{n^2}h^{n^3}=a^nb^{\binom n2}c^{\binom n3}=(ab^{-1/2}c^{1/3})^n(b^{1/2}c^{-1/2})^{n^2}(c^{1/6})^{n^3}$$ gives $c=h^6=1$, so that special case _trivially_ reduces to the classical triple product. I'll have to think more about this, and try to consolidate these wandering comments...

Comment: @mr_e_man : Thanks a lot for your comments. Yes I know, $h^6=1$ works fine Reparametrizing is very good idea. Main problem is the products if really zeros or not as you noted in your your first comment. I asked other related questions about this topic. You can see if you want  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2839426/prove-or-disprove-that-sum-limits-k-1-t-fk-0-where-fm-sum-limits

Comment: For the arrow, instead of writing "- - >" you can use the symbol "\to" or "\mapsto".

Comment: Does this series ever converge (except when it is $0$ or when $|h|=1$) ? When $z,q \ne 0$ and $|h|>1$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} |z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}|=\infty$; but when $z,q \ne 0$ and $0<|h|<1$ we have $\lim_{n\to -\infty} |z^n q^{n^2} h^{n^3}|=\infty$

Comment: @GEdgar  this only converges when $|h|=1$ and $|q|<1$.  You can think that $h=e^{ix}$  that x is a real number.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}z^nq^{n^2}h^{n^3}$$

By your conjecture, this function contains $(1+zqh)$ as a factor. Let's generalize a bit to $(1+zqh^c)$, for some constant $c$. But if that were true, then it would have to vanish when

$$z=-q^{-1}h^{-c},$$

that is,

$$0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}(-1)^nq^{n^2-n}h^{n^3-nc}$$

$$=\cdots+q^6h^{-8+2c}-q^2h^{-1+c}+q^0h^0-q^0h^{1-c}+q^2h^{8-2c}-q^6h^{27-3c}+q^{12}h^{64-4c}-\cdots$$

$$=\big(1-h^{1-c}\big)q^0-\big(h^{-1+c}-h^{8-2c}\big)q^2+\big(h^{-8+2c}-h^{27-3c}\big)q^6-\cdots.$$

Since this is supposed to vanish for all $|q|<1$, all coefficients of powers of $q$ must vanish:

$$h^{1-c}=1,\quad h^{8-2c}=h^{-1+c},\quad h^{27-3c}=h^{-8+2c},\quad\cdots$$

$$h^{1-c}=1,\quad h^{9-3c}=1,\quad h^{35-5c}=1,\quad\cdots$$

and since $h=e^{i\theta}$ is also a variable, while the right sides of the equations are constant, the exponents must vanish:

$$c=1,\quad c=3,\quad c=7,\quad\cdots$$

which is clearly impossible. (More explicitly, if $h^p=e^{i\theta p}=1$, then $\theta p=n2\pi$ for some integer $n$; the right side takes discrete values, while the left side takes a continuum of values unless $p=0$.)

Therefore, $(1+zqh^c)$ is not a factor of the function.

By similar reasoning, for any constants $a,b,c$ with $a\neq0$ and either choice of sign, $(1\pm z^aq^bh^c)$ is not a factor. (There may be factors with $a=0$, but a product of these doesn't depend on $z$, while the original function does depend on $z$.)

Comment: : Thanks a lot for your answer and comment for this old question. I started to work on it again after your comments. It became again active subject for me.   I asked a new question  that I focused on zeros. Maybe you can wish to check it  .Best Regards