# Is there a formula for $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} q^{n^3}$?

Tags: number-theory, power-series, q-series

When I studyied the representation of integers as sum of squares, I found that the most powerful tool is the [Jacobi Triple Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiTripleProduct.html), in fact this amazing identity allows us to find more useful equalities such as:

$$ \prod_{n\geq 1}(1+zq^{2n-1})(1+z^{-1}q^{2n-1})(1-q^{2n})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}z^nq^{n^2}$$
If we take $z\to 1$ we find an expression of $ S=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty} q^{n^2} $ and if we simplify $S^2$ and $S^4$ we can find the number of representation of integers as sum of $2$ squares and $4$ squares respectively which are denoted commonly by $r_2(n)$ and $r_4(n)$. My question: is there any formula which can help us find the number of representation of integers as sums of cubes?, for example a simplified expression for 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^{n}y^{n^2}q^{n^3}$$

I mean by a "simplified expression" an expression which can help us finding an expansion of $S'^2$ or $S'^3$ where $S'=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} q^{n^3}$.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you seen my question  on the subject? I will be appreciated if you check.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358407/extension-of-the-jacobi-triple-product-identity Thanks

Comment: I already tried what you have tried but I did not succeed (My question is older and I thought about a long time ago even before asking it here) Anyway, I think that solving this question is very difficult, I would appreciate if there are some well known mathematicians who tried it?