# Prove or disprove that $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^T f(k)=0 $ where $f(m)=\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ m (-1)^n \sin(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}x) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

$$f(m)=\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ m (-1)^n  \sin\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \frac{a \pi}{b}\right) \tag 1 $$

Where $a,b,m$ positive integers. 
I have tested in WolframAlpha for many $a$ and $b$ values.
I conjecture (**1**) without proof that $f(m)$ function is periodic when $a,b,m$ positive integers and the sum of $f(m)$ is $0$ between period.

Edit: In other way to express my claim above in my conjecture ($1$) that 
$ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^T f(k)=0 $
where ($T$) is the period value.

[The wolframalpha link for testing some $a,b$ values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=compute+sum+(-1)%5En++sin(+(3%5Cpi+%2F17)+n(n%2B1)(2n%2B1)%2F6),+n%3D1+to+200)

I also conjecture (**2**) without proof that the sum of $f(m)$ should be zero if $x$ is any real number.

$$f(m)=\sum\limits_{n = 1 }^ m (-1)^n  \sin\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}x\right) \tag 2 $$

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k = 1 }^ n f(k)=0 \tag 3 $$

1. What is the period formula when $a,b$ are positive integers?
2. Please help me to prove my conjectures **1** and **2** or disprove .

---

Note that:$$\sum\limits_{k = 1 }^ n k^2=  \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $$

**EDIT:**

The period value is ($T$) and $f(m)$ satisfies $f(m)=f(m+kT)$ relation where $k$ is non-negative integer.

**Period values for some $a,b$ values:**

$a=3$, $b=17$ ,$x=\frac{3 \pi}{17} \Rightarrow T=68$  (this example is given in the link) and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{68} f(k)=0  $

$a=1$, $b=2$ ,$x=\frac{ \pi}{2} \Rightarrow T=8$ and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^8 f(k)=0  $

$a=1$, $b=3$ ,$x=\frac{ \pi}{3} \Rightarrow T=36$ and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{36} f(k)=0  $

$a=1$, $b=4$ ,$x=\frac{ \pi}{4} \Rightarrow T=16$ and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{16} f(k)=0  $

$a=1$, $b=5$ ,$x=\frac{ \pi}{5} \Rightarrow T=20$ and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{20} f(k)=0  $

$a=1$, $b=6$ ,$x=\frac{ \pi}{6} \Rightarrow T=72$  and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{72} f(k)=0  $

$a=1$, $b=7$ ,$x=\frac{ \pi}{7} \Rightarrow T=28$  and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{28} f(k)=0  $

$a=2$, $b=7$ ,$x=\frac{ 2\pi}{7} \Rightarrow T=14$  and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{14} f(k)=0  $

$a=3$, $b=7$ ,$x=\frac{ 3\pi}{7} \Rightarrow T=56$  and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{56} f(k)=0  $

$a=4$, $b=7$ ,$x=\frac{ 4\pi}{7} \Rightarrow T=14$  and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{14} f(k)=0  $

$a=5$, $b=7$ ,$x=\frac{ 5\pi}{7} \Rightarrow T=28$  and $ \sum\limits_{k = 1 }^{28} f(k)=0  $

Thanks a lot for answers.

Please note that: I have posted a new question to generalize the problem. [the link to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846329/generalize-conjecture-for-the-problem-fm-sum-limits-n-1-m-1n-sin)

Comment: If you sum  your example from 1 to infinity WA says, that the sum does not converge and gives a zero  result for 'Dirichlet regularization'.

Comment: If $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ converges, then $f(n)$ has to converge to $0$, and if $f(n)$ converges then $(-1)^n\sin(n(n+1)(2n+1)x/6)$ has to converge to $0$, I am really not sure that there are examples where that happens except $x = k\pi$ with $k \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: Adding a new question after answers are posted is in general depreciated. You may ask it by starting a new thread. :)

Comment: @SangchulLee  : You are right. Thanks for advice . I have posted a new question  to generalize the conjecture. Best Regards

Answer (score 14):

Your **conjecture 1** is true and it is stated and proved as follows.
On other hand, **conjecture 2** is false and it is disproved below.

> Let $a,b$ be two coprime and positive integers.
>   Then the function $f$ defined for $m\in\Bbb N$
>   $$f(m)=\sum_{n=0}^m(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\frac{a\pi}b\right)$$
>   has period
>   $$T=\frac{4\gcd(b,3)b}{\gcd(a,2)}$$
>   and
>   $$\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)=0$$

The proof is split in several steps.

> **Lemma 1.** $$\sin(ax\pi/b)=(-1)^h\sin(ay\pi/b)\iff ax\equiv kb+(-1)^{k+h}ay\pmod{2b}$$

*Proof.* We have $\sin(ax\pi/b)=(-1)^h\sin(ay\pi/b)$ if and only if
\begin{align}
&ax\pi/b\equiv(-1)^hay\pi/b\pmod{2\pi}&
&\lor&
&ax\pi/b\equiv\pi-(-1)^hay\pi/b\pmod{2\pi}
\end{align}
that's
\begin{align}
&ax\equiv(-1)^hay\pmod{2b}&
&\lor&
&ax\equiv b-(-1)^hay\pmod{2b}
\end{align}
which is equivalent to $ax\equiv kb+(-1)^{k+h}ay\pmod{2b}$.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $t_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$ be an integer sequence and let for all $m\in\Bbb N$
>   $$f(m)=\sum_{n=0}^m\sin\left(t_n \frac{a\pi}b\right).$$
>   Then
>
> 1. If $at_{T-1-n}\equiv kb-(-1)^kat_n\pmod{2b}$ then $f(T-1)=0$.
> 2. If $at_{T+n}\equiv kb+(-1)^{k+h}at_n\pmod{2b}$, then $f(T+m)=f(T-1)+(-1)^hf(m)$.
> 3. If $f(T+m)=-f(m)$ then $f$ has period $2T$ and $\sum_{m=0}^{2T-1}f(m)=0$.

*Proof of 1.* By Lemma 1 we have $\sin(at_{T-1-n}\pi/b)=-\sin(at_n\pi/b)$ hence
\begin{align}
f(T-1)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}\sin(at_n\pi/b)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}\sin\left(t_{T-1-n}\frac{a\pi}b\right)\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{T-1}\sin\left(t_n\frac{a\pi}b\right)\\
&=-f(T-1)
\end{align}
hence $f(T-1)=0$.

*Proof of 2.* We have
\begin{align}
f(T+m)
&=f(T-1)+\sum_{n=T}^{T+m}\sin(at_n\pi/b)\\
&=f(T-1)+\sum_{n=0}^m\sin(at_{T+n}\pi/b)\\
&=f(T-1)+(-1)^h\sum_{n=0}^m\sin(at_n\pi/b)\\
&=f(T-1)+(-1)^hf(m)
\end{align}

*Proof of 3.* We have $f(2T+m)=-f(T+m)=f(m)$, hence $f$ has period $2T$ and
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^{2T-1}f(m)
&=\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)+\sum_{m=T}^{2T-1}f(m)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)+\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(T+m)\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)-\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)\\
&=0
\end{align}
from which the assertion follows.

> **Lemma 3.** Let for all $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align}
> &s_n=\sum_{k=0}^nk^2,&
> &t_n=(-1)^ns_n,
> \end{align}
>   The for all $n\in\Bbb N$ the following congruences holds:
>   \begin{align}
> t_{b+n}&\equiv(-1)^nt_b+(-1)^bt_n\pmod b\\
> t_{b-1-n}&\equiv(-1)^nt_{b-1}+(-1)^bt_n\pmod b
> \end{align}

*Proof.* We have
\begin{align}
s_{b+n}&
 =\sum_{k=0}^{b+n}k^2&
  s_{b-1-n}&
   =\sum_{k=0}^{b-1-n}k^2\\
&
 =\sum_{k=0}^bk^2+\sum_{k=b+1}^{b+n}k^2&
  &
   =\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}k^2-\sum_{k=b-n}^{b-1}k^2\\
&
 =s_b+\sum_{h=1}^n(b+h)^2&
  &
   =\sum_{k=0}^{b-1}k^2-\sum_{h=1}^n(b-h)^2\\
&
 \equiv s_b+\sum_{h=1}^nh^2&
  &
   \equiv s_{b-1}-\sum_{h=1}^nh^2\\
&
 =s_b+s_n\pmod b&
  &
   \equiv s_{b-1}-s_n\pmod b
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
t_{b+n}&
 =(-1)^{b+n}s_{b+n}&
  t_{b-1-n}&
   =(-1)^{b-1-n}s_{b-1-n}\\
&
 \equiv(-1)^{b+n}s_b+(-1)^{b+n}s_n&
  &
   \equiv (-1)^{b-1-n}s_{b-1}-(-1)^{b-1-n}s_n\\
&
 =(-1)^nt_b+(-1)^bt_n\pmod b&
  &
   =(-1)^nt_{b-1}+(-1)^bt_n\pmod b
\end{align}

Now the proof of main statement.

> If $2\nmid a$, then $f$ has period $T=4\gcd(b,3)b$ and $\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)=0$.

Let $d=\gcd(b,3)$. From Lemma 3
\begin{align}
t_{2db+n}&\equiv(-1)^nt_{2db}+t_n\pmod{2db}\\
t_{2db-1-n}&\equiv(-1)^nt_{2db-1}+t_n\pmod{2db}
\end{align}
Moreover,
\begin{align}
(-1)^nat_{2db}&
=(-1)^na\frac{2db(2db+1)(4db+1)}6&
t_{2db-1}&
=-(-1)^na\frac{(2db-1)2db(4db-1)}6\\
&
=(-1)^na\frac d3(2db+1)(4db+1)b&
&
=-(-1)^na\frac d3(2db-1)(4db-1)b\\
&
\equiv b\pmod{2b}&
&
\equiv b\pmod{2b}
\end{align}
Consequently,
\begin{align}
at_{2db+n}&\equiv b+at_n\pmod{2b}\\
at_{2db-1-n}&\equiv b+at_n\pmod{2b}
\end{align}
hence, by Lemma 2.1, $f(2db-1)=0$, by Lemma 2.2 $f(2db+m)=-f(m)$.
By Lemma 2.3, $f$ has period $4db$ and
$$\sum_{m=0}^{4db-1}f(m)=0$$

> If $2\mid a$, then $f$ has period $T=2\gcd(b,3)b$ and $\sum_{m=0}^{T-1}f(m)=0$.

Since $a,b$ are, by assumption, coprime, we have $2\nmid b$.
Let $d=\gcd(b,3)$.
From Lemma 3 we get
\begin{align}
t_{db+n}&\equiv(-1)^nt_{db}-t_n\pmod{db}\\
t_{db-1-n}&\equiv(-1)^nt_{db-1}-t_n\pmod{db}
\end{align}
Moreover,
\begin{align}
(-1)^nat_{db}&
=(-1)^na\frac{db(db+1)(2db+1)}6&
t_{db-1}&
=-(-1)^na\frac{(db-1)db(2db-1)}6\\
&
=(-1)^n\frac a2\frac d3\frac{db+1}2(2db+1)2b&
&
=-(-1)^n\frac a2\frac d3\frac{db-1}2(2db-1)2b\\
&
\equiv 0\pmod{2b}&
&
\equiv 0\pmod{2b}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
at_{db+n}&\equiv-at_n\pmod{2b}\\
at_{db-1-n}&\equiv-at_n\pmod{2b}
\end{align}
By Lemma 2.1 we have $f(db-1)=0$, while by Lemma 2.2 we get $f(db+m)=-f(m)$.
Finally, by Lemma 2.3, $f$ has period $2db$ and
$$\sum_{m=0}^{2db-1}f(m)=0$$

---

**Conjecture 2** is false.
For let $q$ be a non-zero polynomial with rational coefficients, $x$ be a real number and assume
\begin{align}
&
\sum_{m=0}^\infty f(m)=0&
\text{where }&
f(m)=\sum_{n=0}^m(-1)^n\sin(q(n)x)
\end{align}
If $f(m)\xrightarrow{m\to\infty}0$ then
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sin(q(n)x)=0$$
hence $\sin(q(n)x)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$.
Consequently $e^{2ixq(n)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$, hence $x\in\pi\Bbb Q$ by the Lemma 4 below.

> **Lemma 4.** Let $p$ be a non-zero polynomial with coefficients in $\Bbb Q$ and $x$ be a real number.
>   If $e^{ixp(n)}\xrightarrow{\Bbb N\ni n\to\infty}1$, then $x\in\pi\Bbb Q$.

*Proof.* By induction on $\deg p$.
If $\deg p=0$, then $e^{iax}=1$ for some $a\in\Bbb Q$ ($a\neq 0$).
This implies $ax\in 2\pi\Bbb Z$, hence $x\in\pi\Bbb Q$.

If $\deg p>0$, then $q(n)=p(n)-p(n-1)$ is a non-zero polynomial with $\deg q<\deg p$ and
$$e^{ixq(n)}=\frac{e^{ixp(n)}}{e^{ixp(n-1)}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$
hence $x\in\pi\Bbb Q$ by induction hypothesys.

Comment: I also obtained the same answer for the period $T$. Anyway, I am curious if your solution proves that your choice of $T$ is the *minimal* period of $f$. I am asking this because I failed to prove this despite of my suspicion that this must be true. Perhaps your solution already demonstrates this, but please forgive my laziness as I feel too exhausted to read it thoroughly...

Comment: No, I don't proved the minimality of that period too...

Comment: @FabioLucchini : Thanks a lot for your answer. I have added a new conjecture in my question. Can we generalize the problem? Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Settings and main results

Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime integers. Let $\theta, e, F $ be defined by

\begin{align*}
\theta_n = \frac{a}{b}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 \right) + n, \qquad
e_n = \exp\{i\pi\theta_n\}, \qquad
F_m = \sum_{n=1}^{m} e_n.
\end{align*}

(Here, we extend $\sum$ by additivity to allow non-positive arguments for $\theta$ and $F$.) This definition is related to OP's question by $f(m) = \operatorname{Im}\left( F_m \right)$. In view of this, we will prove the following result.

> **Proposition.** The smallest positive period  $T_{\min}$ of $\{e_n\}$ is given by
>   $$ T_{\min} = \frac{4\gcd(b, 3)}{\gcd(a, 2)}b. \tag{1} $$
>   Moreover, $F$ has period $T_{\min}$ and satisfies 
>   $$ \operatorname{Im} \left( \sum_{m=1}^{T_{\min}} F_m \right) = 0. $$

To establish this result, we aim to prove the following lemmas.

- > **Lemma 1.** An integer $T$ is a period of $\{e_n\}$ if and only if the following conditions hold
  >   $ $
  >
  > 1. $\text{(P1)} \ $ $T = 2bp$ for some integer $p$, and
  > 2. $\text{(P2)} \ $ $2 \mid ap$ and $3 \mid ap(2bp+1)(4bp+1)$.
- > **Lemma 2.** Let $T$ be a period of $\{e_n\}$ and write $U = \frac{T}{2}$. Then
  >
  > 1. $e_{n+U} = e_U e_n$ and $e_{U-1-n} = -e_U \overline{e_n}$.
  > 2. $e_U = \pm 1$ and $e_{U-1} = -e_U$.
  > 3. If $e_U = 1$, then $U$ is also a period of $\{e_n\}$.

Let us see how this leads to the desired main result.

*Proof of Proposition using Lemmas.* It is easy to check that $\text{(1)}$ is the smallest positive $T$ satisfying both $\text{(P1)}$ and $\text{(P2)}$. Writing $U = T_{\min}/2$ for simplicity, it follows from the minimality of $T_{\min}$ and Lemma 2 that $U$ is not a period of $\{e_n\}$. In particular, we have $e_U = -1$. Then

$$ F_{T_{\min}}
= \sum_{n=1}^{U} (e_n + e_{U+n})
= \sum_{n=1}^{U} (e_n - e_n) 
= 0. $$

Moreover, since $e_{U-1} + e_U = 0$ and $e_{-1} + e_0 = 0$, we have

$$ F_U
= \sum_{n=-1}^{U-2} e_n
= \sum_{n=1}^{U} e_{U-1-n}
= \sum_{n=1}^{U} \overline{e_n}
= \overline{F_U}. $$

This implies that $\operatorname{Im}(F_U) = 0$. Finally, it follows that

$$ \sum_{m=1}^{T} F_m
= \sum_{m=1}^{U} (F_m + F_{U+m})
= \sum_{m=1}^{U} (F_m + F_U - F_m)
= UF_U $$

and therefore $ \operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{T} F_m \right) = 0$ as required.

---

### 2. Proofs of lemmas

Before proving these claims, we introduce an auxlilary quantity which will be useful throughout the solution. Set

$$ \Delta_{m,n} = \theta_{m+n} - \theta_m - \theta_n = \frac{a}{b}mn(m+n+1). $$

It is obvious that $e_{m+n} = e_m e_n \exp\{i\pi\Delta_{m,n}\}$ holds for any $m, n$. In particular, this implies that

$$ \text{$T$ is a period of $\{e_n\}$}
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
\begin{cases}
\theta_T \equiv 0 \pmod{2}, \\
\Delta_{T,n} \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

Now we proceed to prove Lemma 1 first.

**Proof of Lemma 1.** One direction is almost immediate. Indeed, assume that both $\text{(P1)}$ and $\text{(P2)}$ hold. Then we easily check that both $\Delta_{n,T}$ and $\theta_T$ are even integers, hence $T$ is a period in view of $\text{(2)}$. So we focus on proving the other direction.

Assume that $T$ is a period of $\{e_n\}$. Using $\text{(2)}$, we know that both

$$ \Delta_{T,2} - 2\Delta_{T,1} = \frac{2aT}{b} \quad \text{and} \quad \Delta_{T,2} - 3\Delta_{T,1} = -\frac{aT^2}{b} $$

are all even integers. Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, the first identity implies that $q = T/b$ is an integer and hence the same is true for $S = qa = aT/b$. Then the second identity tells that $2 \mid ST$. Now let us expand $\theta_T$ as

$$ \theta_T = \frac{S(T+1)(2T+1)}{6} + T = \frac{S(2T^2 + 1)}{6} + \frac{ST}{2} + T. $$

Since $\frac{ST}{2} + T$ is integer and $2 \nmid 2T^2 + 1$, we obtain $2 \mid S$. Then we find that $2 \mid T$ as well, for otherwise $6(\theta_T - T)$ is not a multiple of $4$ while $6(\theta_T - T) = S(T+1)(2T+1) $ is a multiple of $4$, which is a contradiction.

So far we have proved that $b \mid T$ and $2 \mid S, T$. Since $q = \gcd(S, T)$, we may write $q = 2p$, proving $\text{(P1)}$. Plugging this back to $\theta_T$,

$$ 0
\equiv \theta_T
\equiv \frac{S(T+1)(2T+1)}{6}
\equiv \frac{ap(2bp+1)(4bp+1)}{3} \pmod {2}, $$

from which $\text{(P2)}$ follows.  ////

**Proof of Lemma 2.** Let $T$ be a period of $\{e_n\}$ and let $p$ be as in Lemma 1. Write $U = \frac{T}{2}$. Then

$$ \Delta_{n,U} = apn(bpn+n+1)
\quad \text{and} \quad
\Delta_{n,U-1-n} = apn(bp-n-1) $$

are multiples of $ap$, which is even. So

$$e_{n+U} = e_n e_U \exp\{i\pi\Delta_{n,U}\} = e_n e_{U}.$$

Then plugging $n = U$ yields $1 = e_T = e_U^2$ and hence $e_U = \pm 1$. Similarly,

$$e_{U-1} = e_n e_{U-1-n} \exp\{i\pi\Delta_{n,U-1-n}\} = e_n e_{U-1-n}. $$

Then plugging $n = -1$ yields $e_{U-1} = e_{-1}e_U = -e_U$ and $e_{U-1-n} = -e_U \overline{e_n}$ as required. Finally, if $e_U = 1$, then we have $e_{n+U} = e_n$ and therefore $U$ is also a period.  ////

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have added a new conjecture in my question. Can we generalize the problem?  Best Regards