# Has there been any exploration on Cubic Power Series?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, functional-equations, theta-functions, lacunary-series

I was interested in finding some identities/special values involving the function $$\gamma(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} z^{i^3} = 1 + z + z^8 + z^{27} + ... $$

which can be thought of as a "cubic generalization of the famous
$$\theta(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} z^{i^2} = 1 + z + z^4 + z^9 + ... $$

Which can be cooked up using jacobi theta functions.

Unfortunately the term "cubic theta function" doesn't lead to any insight on this series since the "cubic" is reserved for a type of identity as opposed to the form of the series.

Surely these have been looked at before does anyone have any links/intel about them?

Comment: See some posts in https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20z%5E%7Bi%5E3%7D%24&p=1

Comment: The Mellin transform of $\gamma(e^{-x})$ is $\zeta(3s)\Gamma(s)$, the equivalent of $\theta(e^{-\pi x})=x^{-1/2}\theta(e^{-\pi/x})$ involves a convolution.

Comment: Related: [Extension of the Jacobi triple product identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358407/472818)

Answer (score 1):

Results found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427918/is-anything-known-about-the-series-sum-n-0-infty-x-sqrtn are general enough to be applied to the cubic power series as well